# python docx installed but cannot be imported

Tags: docx, importerror, gae-python27

Hi I'm using windows and installing python-docx using pip. I went into C:\Python27\Scripts and ran `pip install python-docx` . I thought it should have been installed.

But when i run a simple import

from docx import Documents

it ran into an "ImportError: No module named docx"
when i checked the modules installed using pip using `pip list` python-docx 0.8.7 is installed. Does anyone know why whis is happening?

Update : I just found out the script runs when i run the script on windows command line, but it doesn't run on IDLE could it be some configurations on IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

It is not Documents just Document

It should just be:

```
from docx import Document
```

Also here is an example from the documentation:

[Documentation for command](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: still the same. The error is an Import error for docx
'ImportError: No module named docx'

Comment: What is the version of python being used in the IDLE window it may differ from your command line

Comment: If it is different pythons check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions

Comment: same version i only have python 2.7 installed in my compute right now. i have a suspicition it is to do with system paths

Comment: Then add to your system path the python directory, for instance, mine is C://python34

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone is still having problem, please update your setuptools and install python-docx.

pip install -U setuptools

pip install --pre python-docx